# changing image src from array using jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, image

I want to change the src of a few images. The urls are stored in a array randomly but the pictures are not showing. The images are stored in an `/img` folder.

```
var images=["img/Square.png","img/Star.png","img/Circle.png","img/Triangle.png","img/Ellipse.png","img/Rectangle.png"];

var image1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
var image2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
var image3 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);

$("#img1").attr("src",images[image1]);
$("#img2").attr("src",images[image2]);
$("#img3").attr("src",images[image3]);
```

My html Code is :

```
<div class="tag1" >
     <img id="img1" class="img-responsive" src="" alt=""  width="25%"  /> 
     <img id="img2" class="img-responsive" src="" alt=""  width="25%" style="margin-left:10%;"  >
     <img id="img3" class="img-responsive" src="" alt=""  width="25%" style="margin-left:10%;" >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`"images"` is not a string its a variable(array).

Try this,

```
 $("#img1").attr("src", images[image1]);
```

**updated (after comment):**

your random value sometimes gets `6` which is not present in the array change it to 5

```
  var image1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 1);
```

and add all of your code inside ready function.

```
$(function(){
      var images=["img/Square.png","img/Star.png","img/Circle.png","img/Triangle.png","img/Ellipse.png","img/Rectangle.png"];

     var image1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 1);
     var image2 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 1);
     var image3 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 1);

      $("#img1").attr("src",images[image1]);
      $("#img2").attr("src",images[image2]);
      $("#img3").attr("src",images[image3]);
  });
```

Comment: i tried with quotaion and without quotation .but its not showing any picture

Comment: Also make sure your css for `img-responsive` is not causing the error.

Comment: when i change the image src directly in HTML its showing the image .but not showing using array

Comment: ok this may sounds stupid  just to confirm do you have your script inside document.ready function

Comment: i solved my problem by changing my script coding from center to end of document .

Comment: but now its showing some time 2 images ,some time 1 image and some time 3 what is the problem

Comment: problem solved i change the code `var image1 = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 1);` and now its showing all three images

Comment: My doubt was right.. your script is not inside document.ready function and hence it worked when you move your code to the end and for not dispalying image the random value also gets 6 which is not a array key. Let me update my answer

Answer (score 1):

The image array has 6 items with array indexes 0,1,2,3,4,5.

```
Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1)
```

This generates a random number between 1 - 6. You may be getting an error (no image) if it ever generates a 6 because there is no index 6. Max is 5. Change it to:

```
Math.floor((Math.random() * 6))
```

Everything else in the code you supplied looks correct.

Comment: You are right i changed my value from *6 to *5 and now its showing all pictures

Answer (score 0):

```js
var x

function shufflerandomay() {
    x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 4))
}

var groupImg1 = [
    "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1530651788726-1dbf58eeef1f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=882&q=80",
    "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1559386484-97dfc0e15539?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1234&q=80",
    "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1533461502717-83546f485d24?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=900&q=60",
    "https://tse2.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.hjBODA9luVr29wosa528_AHaJ4&pid=Api"
];

var groupImg2 = [
    "https://tse3.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.e3osvFsA7n8pz3DQ8wIiZQHaLH&pid=Api",
    "https://tse2.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.hjBODA9luVr29wosa528_AHaJ4&pid=Api",
    "https://tse3.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.CFC2G9JinfIvZUcXheEPogHaLG&pid=Api",
    "https://tse2.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.ZKmrVM1RDpBkM-Ci4zIVUgHaJ4&pid=Api"
];

var groupImg3 = [
    "https://tse2.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.POLdja72DCes6PMNvp0T-gHaJQ&pid=Api",
    "https://tse2.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.ZKmrVM1RDpBkM-Ci4zIVUgHaJ4&pid=Api",
    "https://tse1.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.os-yHe1FYwTDWnDXiCuUCAHaLH&pid=Api",
    "https://tse2.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.muJtFt8tt4knnW4JxPwGBAHaLG&pid=Api"
];

$(document).ready(function() {
    shufflerandomay(groupImg1[x])
    $("#img1").attr("src", groupImg1[x])
    shufflerandomay(groupImg2[x])
    $("#img2").attr("src", groupImg2[x])
    shufflerandomay(groupImg3[x])
    $("#img3").attr("src", groupImg3[x])
});


$('input').on('click', function() {
    shufflerandomay(groupImg1[x])
    shufflerandomay(groupImg2[x])
    shufflerandomay(groupImg3[x])

    $("#img1").attr("src", groupImg1[x])
    $("#img2").attr("src", groupImg2[x])
    $("#img3").attr("src", groupImg3[x])
});
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=DM+Sans:400,500,700&display=swap");
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 30px 10px;
    font-family: "DM Sans", sans-serif;
    transition: background 0.4s ease-in;
    background-color: #0098fd;
}

body.mentol {
    background-color: #06c7ad;
}

input[type=radio] {
    display: none;
}

.card {
    position: absolute;
    width: 60%;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    transition: transform 0.7s ease;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 800px;
    max-height: 600px;
    height: 100%;
}

.cards {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border-radius: 10px;
    -o-object-fit: cover;
    object-fit: cover;
}

#item-1:checked~.cards #message-3,
#item-2:checked~.cards #message-1,
#item-3:checked~.cards #message-2 {
    transform: translatex(-40%) scale(0.8);
    opacity: 0.4;
    z-index: 0;
}

#item-1:checked~.cards #message-2,
#item-2:checked~.cards #message-3,
#item-3:checked~.cards #message-1 {
    transform: translatex(40%) scale(0.8);
    opacity: 0.4;
    z-index: 0;
}

#item-1:checked~.cards #message-1,
#item-2:checked~.cards #message-2,
#item-3:checked~.cards #message-3 {
    transform: translatex(0) scale(1);
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: 1;
}

#item-1:checked~.cards #message-1 img,
#item-2:checked~.cards #message-2 img,
#item-3:checked~.cards #message-3 img {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(81, 81, 81, 0.47);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>CodePen - Playlist Carousel - css only</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/normalize/5.0.0/normalize.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

</head>

<body>

    <div class="container">

        <input type="radio" name="slider" id="item-1" checked>
        <input type="radio" name="slider" id="item-2">
        <input type="radio" name="slider" id="item-3">

        <div class="cards">

            <label class="card" for="item-1" id="message-1">
                <img id="img1" src="https://tse3.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.e3osvFsA7n8pz3DQ8wIiZQHaLH&pid=Api">
              </label>

            <label class="card middleCard" for="item-2" id="message-2">
                <img id="img2" src="https://tse3.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.CFC2G9JinfIvZUcXheEPogHaLG&pid=Api">
              </label>

            <label class="card" for="item-3" id="message-3">
                <img id="img3" src="https://tse1.mm.bing.net/th?id=OIP.os-yHe1FYwTDWnDXiCuUCAHaLH&pid=Api">
              </label>

            <!-- end of cards -->
        </div>

        <!-- end of container -->
    </div>

    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: If you had explained your code I think this would have been the accepted answer